# How to Extend Ubuntu OS Partition Size from Unallocated Partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.10, gparted

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 ( along with Windows 7 ) in a partition of around 35 GB. Recently I need to extend this size due to lack of space. So I have shrink 25 GB space from Windows ( left as unallocated partition ).

After some googling I got some articles abot how to do that, but known of them was helpful.

Can anyone help to extend Ubuntu OS partition. It will helpful if step by step process can be provided.

I have attached a screenshot of current partition structure.

[Ubuntu Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0kFs.png)

- Thanks

Comment: No simple way to do it in your case. The unallocated space is not next to /dev/sda7. It would be necessary to move /dev/sda3 out of the way, for which there isn't enough space. Any chance you can delete /dev/sda3?

Comment: If there is no solution than I need to delete...

Comment: A standard partition cannot grow to incorporate unallocated space that is non-adjacent. This is what LVM was designed to solve.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you have good backups. You have to play the old slide puzzle game, First move sda3 left into unallocated. That will be very slow. Best to defrag & houseclean as much as possible. And before anything else boot Windows & run chkdsk on sda3. The move extended partition left so unallocated is inside extended partition. Then move sda7 left and expand right. Also slow. Any interruption of move will totally corrupt data. Make sure connected to power if laptop & do not do during thunderstorm. You have to use live installer as little keys say partitions are mounted.

Comment: @mikewhatever please see my "short" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply assemble several non-juxtaposed pieces of partition into one in a *normal* paritioning scheme.

To achieve what you want to do, you would need to reinstall the Ubuntu part (remember to do yoru backups first!), using LVM (Logical Volume Management)

Under such circumstances, you would indeed be able to add individual partitions to a volume group, and piece them together to make a single logical volume.

The advantage of this approach is that additionally, you can make your Ubuntu partition grow to also include additional drives etc.

See [here the section on installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html) using Logical Volume Manager

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer...

## First, backup everything that you care about, because move/resizes like this can loose or corrupt data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

So do this:

- **move** sda3 partition left (do this from Windows using the Disk Management app, if you can, because it's NTFS. Otherwise use gparted.)
- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and start `gparted`
- issue a `swapoff` on sda8
- **resize** the left side of sda4 left
- **move** sda7 partition left
- **resize** the right side of sda7 right
- issue a `swapon` on sda8

Comment: Yes, it's possible this way, but sit should be stressed this should only happen as an emergency, not as a routine method...

Comment: @taifwa I help people do this all the time. As long as they have good backups. Never lost any data so far.