# How should I increase the size of the root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

sorry if this question is a duplicate (first-time poster), but I want to make sure I don't majorly screw up my partitions.
My root (/) partition is running low on space, and I have ~20GB of unallocated space at the end of my hard drive which I could use. How should I go about shuffling partitions so I can expand the size of the root partition?
Thanks in advance!

Here's a picture of my current partition setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXvFH.png

Comment: This question also asked today https://askubuntu.com/questions/907076/how-to-extend-ubuntu-os-partition-size-from-unallocated-partition is the same and the answer would be the same. The partition you want to extend to is non-adjacent, so cannot be formed into your existing partitions. You *could* create a separate partition, and mount that somewhere under root, to free up some space, but it is inelegant as a solution

Comment: @taifwa Thanks for your response. I'll probably use this inelegant solution, as I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consideration, and @taifwa's help I was able to solve the problem. What I did was:

1. Move the Windows diagnostics/recovery partition to the end of the hard drive
2. Extend the extended partition to include the unallocated space
3. Move the swap & home partition to the end of the extended partition
4. Extend the root partition to include the unallocated space.

This worked for me.

Comment: How did you "move" the partitions - does Windows's partition manager offer this for any partitions or just the Windows ones? I'm sure the asker on the other question would appreciate your answering their question, if you can provide more explanatory details ;-)

Comment: @taifwa I just used GParted in a live session booted off of a USB Flash device. When I right-clicked the partitions, I could select "Move/Resize" and thus move them around. However, I wouldn't do this in Shimul's case, as it would result in the Start Sector of /boot being moved, which could result in the system becoming unbootable. I was lucky, because the unallocated space was at the very end of the hard drive, and so I didn't have to shuffle around the root partition itself.